# WCF Service msg Size Error

Tags: wcf, web, service, reference

I've two separated module (web based GUI and WCF based Server) and I'm using WCF service reference to access some methods from my GUI to Server. The problem occurs when GUI requests data from Server and it sends huge amount of data to GUI; Maximum Message Size error exception is thrown!
I increased the message size in appropriate section tag in Web.config file and it temporarily worked, but when the data- that is always growing in my case- reaches to the maximum allowed size the error happens again! I know that the bottle neck is on GUI side!
How can I solve the issue and is there any way to make the GUI service reference to handle ever-growing data?
Here is my GUI web.config file:

```
<pre>
</system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServerHelper" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="16777216" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="16777216" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true" >
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://172.16.16.7:123456/ServerServices" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServerHelper" contract="ServiceReference1.IServerHelper" name="BasicHttpBinding_IServerHelper"/>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</pre>
```

thanks for helping me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set these values up to `int.MaxValue`. If that's still not enough for your return message, you should try to split your messages. After all, that would be a message of 2GB. Maybe SOAP is not the best way to transport such a beast.

Comment: How can I split my message? What alternative do you suggest? (giving code sample is great!)

Comment: @user2240957 That very much depends on your use case. Especially considering that sending 2GB over SOAP is not a great way to start with. If you need to get 2GB data, consider a way better suited to that task. Does your client have 6GB RAM? Because that's what you will need if you do MVVM in your GUI and you receive 2GB from your service.

Comment: You say the right nvoigt! I should use a more suitable solution

Comment: But is it possible to maximize the receiving data container size on GUI with current scenario? There are some parameters in web.config that I don't know their benefit (like maxArrayLength ...)

Comment: @user2240957 You can set them all to `int.MaxValue` or it's equivalent in numbers, but do you have an actual problem? If you have an error message, post it.

Comment: Yes, This is the exception: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Comment: @user2240957 this is not what you posted as config here. The error is as obvious as it gets. Put a bigger number for `MaxReceivedMessageSize`. Keep in mind that you send a message to the server and the server sends one back. If both are large, you need to set this on both the client *and* the server.

Comment: exception is the same but in the number! Whatever I increase the number in config it reaches to the threshold and error occurs again. I just want to know if there is any way to make GUI not to Hang in large data receiving without needing to make considerable changes in code?